# Can I find any sample of latest PAX Exam for testing OSGi declarative service bundle with Java 8?

Tags: osgi-bundle, pax-exam, pax-runner

I am trying to create test environment with latest pax-exam-container-forked and Java 8, but there are many conflicts but it is not being resolved due to many dependency with different versions on maven.

I have taken ref from [earcam's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033222/osgi-using-servicefactories/7080234) answer, that is explained very well and that is with very old pax exam and java 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAX Exam and PAX Runner won't work together. 
A long long time ago PAX Exam used to rely on PAX Runner, but this isn't the case anymore since version 2 of PAX Exam (current version is 4). 
Therefore stick to the official documentation of PAX Exam and since you added PAX Web as another tag to the question, just take a look at how PAX Web itself uses PaX Exam to do integration tests. There are plenty of resources available at the [itests](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/pax-web-itest) of Pax Web